# Select 2 columns from multidimensional array - list comprehension

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension

I'm feeling extra dumb tonight.  If I have a basic multi-dimensional list:

```
my_list = [['Bob', 43, 'Tall', 'Green'],
           ['Sally', 32, 'Short', 'Blue'],
           ['Tom', 54,'Medium','Orange']]
```

I can easily use a list comprehension to grab the first column:

```
new_list = [row[0] for row in my_list]
```

or I can grab 3 columns:

```
new_list = [row[0:3] for row in my_list]
```

but how would I grab columns 1 and 3 only?

```
new_list = [row[0,2] for row in my_list]
```

if not with a list comprehension, then how to accomplish with the least amount of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
new_list = [[row[0], row[2]] for row in my_list]
```

In this approach you're constructing a new list yourself for each row and you're putting element `0` and `2` in there as elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator

In [7]: answer = [operator.itemgetter(0,2)(s) for s in my_list]

In [8]: answer
Out[8]: [('Bob', 'Tall'), ('Sally', 'Short'), ('Tom', 'Medium')]
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can certainly use `itemgetter` - which you don't need to assign to a variable, nor do you need to fully qualify its name:

```
from operator import itemgetter
[itemgetter(0,2)(row) for row in my_list]
```

You could also just do what `itemgetter` does, which in this case would mean a nested list comprehension inside your list comprehension:

```
[[row[i] for i in [0,2]] for row in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Simeon Visser wrote, you could also use itemgetter:

```
my_list = [['Bob', 43, 'Tall', 'Green'],
           ['Sally', 32, 'Short', 'Blue'],
           ['Tom', 54,'Medium','Orange']]

from operator import itemgetter

itg = itemgetter(0,2)

print([itg(row) for row in my_list])
```

Gives:

```
[('Bob', 'Tall'), ('Sally', 'Short'), ('Tom', 'Medium')]
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thx. Haven't noticed that.